# Passing an offset Range to a function in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pass a range, but instead, I'm passing values to a function `colorTap`:

```
i = -1
lastCol = 13 
colorTap(Range(Range("B4").Offset(i,-1), Range("B4").Offset(i,lastCol))
```

```
Function colorTap(x as Range)
   x.Select
   With Selection.Interior
      'Does something
   End With
End Function
```

Comment: "but instead, I'm passing values" - what makes you think that?  FYI no need for `Select` here - you can just use `With x.Interior`   If `colorTap` doesn't return any value then it should be a Sub, not a function, and whenever you call a method and don't capture a return value you should not put parentheses around the arguments, so `colorTap Range(Range("B4").Offset(i,-1), Range("B4").Offset(i,lastCol)`   Parentheses cause the argument to be *evaluated* before being passed to the method, which might be the cuase of the problem you're seeing.

Comment: When I ```Debug.print Range("B4").Offset(i,-1)```, it prints the cell value

Comment: You can't print a `Range` object (how would that look?) so you instead get its *default property*, which is `Value`

Comment: If that doesn't clear things up please add more detail about the specific problem you're having.  What is your code doing or not doing that's different from what you expect?

Comment: Your first comment solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `colorTap` doesn't return any value then it should be a Sub, not a function, and whenever you call a method and don't capture a return value, you should not put parentheses around the arguments:

```
colorTap Range(Range("B4").Offset(i,-1), Range("B4").Offset(i,lastCol)
```

Unneeded parentheses cause the argument to be evaluated before being passed to the method, which might be the cause of the problem you're seeing.

FYI no need for `Select` here - you can just use `With x.Interior`